# Syntax error in Python GUI program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying a simple GUI program in python. I'm kinda beginner in Python GUI programming. Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter
class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def_init_(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk._init_(self.parent)
        self.parent = parent    #Self keeps a reference for parent
        self.initialize()

    def intialization(self):
        self.grid()

        #Text widget
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        #Button widget
        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text='Click meeeee!!')
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        #Lable widget
        lable = Tkinter.Lable(self,anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        lable.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,stick='EW')
        self.grid_columnfigure(0,weight=1)


    #main function
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = simpleapp_tk(None)
        app.title('My app')
        app.mainloop()
```

When I compile it, it is returning an error like this:

```
File "secondGUI.py", line 3
    def_init_(self,parent):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You want `def __init__`, not `def_init_`. Note that there are two underscores before and after `init`, and a space between `def` and the first underscore.

Comment: You also are calling `self.initialize`, but the function you made is actually called `initialization`.

Answer (score 0):

As dano said before:

```
import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(parent) # <-- self is already here, implicit self

        self.parent = parent    # <-- okay as long as you are in __init__
        self.initialization()

...
```

Syntax highlighting would have solved your problem ;)

Otherwise I'd suggest PyCharm Studio. Helps a lot

Comment: Your answer would be better if you described what you did differently rather than referencing another answer or comment. Otherwise the OP is forced to go line by line looking for differences.

Answer (score 0):

There is just small a mistake and here i have sorted and i tried it and got the output :

```
import tkinter
class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def _init_(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk._init_(self.parent)
        self.parent = parent    #Self keeps a reference for parent
        self.initialize()

    def intialization(self):
        self.grid()

        #Text widget
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        #Button widget
        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text='Click meeeee!!')
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        #Lable widget
        lable = Tkinter.Lable(self,anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        lable.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,stick='EW')
        self.grid_columnfigure(0,weight=1)


    #main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('My app')
    app.mainloop()
```

Here you can given some extra space in main function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZh9R.png